# Add nodes in a Graph not working perfectly in js

Tags: javascript, data-structures, graph

I have created a graph which containing key and value pair ,key is for node number and value for adjacency list value which is an array of adjacent edges, here I wrote a function that will add the node and adjacency edges in the graph, but here the function is not working ,which thing should I have to modified here that I want graph like { 1:[2,4],2:[1,3],3:[2,4],4:[1,4],5:[3,4]}
code is given below

```
var graph = {
    1: [2, 4],
    2: [1, 3],
    3: [2, 4],
    4: [1, 4]
  };
  function addNode(key, value = []) {
    graph[key].push({ value: value });
  }
  addNode(5, [3, 4]);
  console.log(graph);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function addNode(key, value = []) {
  graph[key] = value;
}
```

Or, if you want to add new values to the node, given it already existed:

```js
function addNode(key, values = []) {
  (graph[key] ??= []).push(...values);
}
```

Try it:

```js
var graph = {
  1: [2, 4],
  2: [1, 3],
  3: [2, 4],
  4: [1, 4]
};

function addNode(key, value = []) {
  graph[key] = value;
}

function addValuesToNode(key, value = []) {
  (graph[key] ??= []).push(...value);
}

addNode(5, [3, 4]);
console.log(graph);

addValuesToNode(5, [1]);
console.log(graph);
```